# MediaRecorder.start failed after MediaPlayer.create

Tags: android, video, duration, mediarecorder

I'm using the following line to get a video duration:

```
int msec = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.fromFile(new File(outputfilename))).getDuration();
```

After that, I'm launching:

```
try {
                mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                        "Error", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but the application crashes on MediaRecorder.start failed.
Is there a correlation between MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder ?
Should I free MediaPlayer resource and how ?

Comment: MediaPlayer.create(); returns a MediaPlayer object. why are you assigning it to an int variable?

Comment: I'm getting a video duration integer value

Comment: did you add the permissions to the android manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: Logcats would be useful here.